# How does 'exists' affect output

Tags: exists

I previously asked a question about how to organize a long search query.  I have taken it apart.  I am presently attempting to understand the function of some of its parts.  Specifically, I am attempting to determine how an `exists` statement works. Does it return a single row or multiple rows?

```
exists(select ID
       From Address
       Join PersonAddress on PersonAddress.Address = Address.ID
       Where
       PersonAddress.Person = Person.ID 
       and ((Description LIKE keyword)
         or(Street LIKE KEYWORD)
         or(City LIKE KEYWORD)
         or(State like KEYWORD)
        ))
```

Comment: exists returns a boolean value of true if the subquery returns at least one row, and false if the subquery returns 0 rows. So in your case, this exists() block will equal true if at least one address exists for the given person, which satisfies description/street/... conditions.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific rdbms?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Microsoft Docs page for the EXISTS operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql):

> EXISTS returns TRUE if a subquery contains **any** rows.

The [PostgreSQL documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html) says this about the `exists` function:

> The argument of EXISTS is an arbitrary SELECT statement, or subquery. **The subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows.** If it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is "true"; if the subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is "false".

Therefore, an EXISTS statement is used as a boolean expression to determine if some subset of rows exists for a given situation.

Take the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    key_value int
);

INSERT INTO table1 (key_value)
VALUES (0)
    , (1)
    , (2)
    , (3);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    key_value int
);

INSERT INTO table2 (key_value)
VALUES (0)
    , (2);
```

So, `table1` contains 4 rows, and `table2` contains 2 rows.

This query will show results from `table1` where the `key_value` matches *any* row in `table2` that has the same `key_value`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.key_value = table1.key_value
    );
```

```
╔═══════════╗
║ key_value ║
╠═══════════╣
║ 0         ║
║ 2         ║
╚═══════════╝
```

This is *similar* to a simple `INNER JOIN` in that only rows where key_value matches in both tables are returned, however there are several key differences:

1. The results only show columns contained in `table1`, whereas an `INNER JOIN` query like the one below returns columns from *both* tables.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM table1
       INNER JOIN table2 
           ON table1.key_value = table2.key_value;
   ```

   ```
       ╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
       ║ key_value ║ key_value ║
       ╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
       ║ 0         ║ 0         ║
       ║ 2         ║ 2         ║
       ╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
   ```
2. If there are multiple rows in `table2` that match a single row in `table1`, only a single row is returned by the `EXISTS` query, whereas multiple rows (the cartesian product of matching rows in `table1` and `table2`) would be returned by the `INNER JOIN` query.  Let's insert another row into `table2` so we have two rows where `key_value` is `2`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO table2 (key_value)
   VALUES (2);

   SELECT *
   FROM table1
       INNER JOIN table2 
           ON table1.key_value = table2.key_value;
   ```

   ```
    ╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
    ║ key_value ║ key_value ║
    ╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
    ║ 0         ║ 0         ║
    ║ 2         ║ 2         ║
    ║ 2         ║ 2         ║
    ╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
   ```

   The `EXISTS` version of the query still only returns two rows:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM table1
   WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM table2
       WHERE table2.key_value = table1.key_value
       );
   ```

```
        ╔═══════════╗
        ║ key_value ║
        ╠═══════════╣
        ║ 0         ║
        ║ 2         ║
        ╚═══════════╝
```